# Compute minimal schedule length for a set of tasks

Tags: list, prolog

```
duration(a,5).
duration(b,7).
duration(c,3).

prereqs(a,[]).
prereqs(b,[]).
prereqs(c,[b]).

?- len([a,b,c],Time).
Time = 10.
```

The question is, Find the total time taken for the tasks to be completed; the tasks do all start at the same time so task C is the longest and will take 10 seconds as it has to complete the prereq task of b.

I've been struggling on this question for a few days now and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the predicate called `cumulative`

Comment: What have you tried so far?